# set a name to sleep process in shell

Tags: shell, process, sleep

I'm a newbie to linux and has a task of writing a script to automate some work

Currently I have a script (runme.csh) with content like this

```
#!/bin/csh -f

read some settings from a file>

while (some condition)

< do some work >

sleep 600

end
```

Now I need to run copies of the script multiple times (copy the script to new file name and run) on same shell [tcsh]

example

[aruna>] runme1.csh &

[aruna>] runme2.csh &

[aruna>] runme3.csh &

Now if I wanted to kill one run I can do ps, find the PID of respective script by its name and kill. However I have no way to find the pid of the sleep command that script executed.

Is there a way to give a name to the sleep process so that I can see which sleep process is executed by which script?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't properly do that using `bash` alone, as `exec -a foo sleep 100` still shows up as `sleep` when using `ps`:

```
[~ ]$ ps -u corion
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
...
101468 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
101494 pts/8    00:00:00 sleep
```

But using Perl, you can easily change the name of the process because Perl supports
assignment to `$0` (the name of the process, in Perl):

```
perl -wle '$0=shift;sleep shift' sleeper 100

[~ ]$ ps -u corion
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
...
100740 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
104067 pts/8    00:00:00 sleeper
```

The above oneliner changes the name to the first argument given and then sleeps as many seconds as the second argument given.

Comment: Hi Corion,Thanks for your valuable input. But it didn't work. I can see "perl" as the process, not "sleeper"

Comment: @arunarubashinghe: Oh, that's bad - on RHEL6 (with whatever kernel) that worked, and on a Debian 9.5  3.16.43-2+deb8u2 kernel, it also works.